# error: property 'contacts' and 'mozContacts' does not exist on 'Navigator' in Angular8 project

Tags: angular, typescript, navigator

I want to open users contacts page from my Angular app. I saw an example in [whatwebcando.today](https://whatwebcando.today/contacts.html)
and I tried to run it on my project with openContacts() method that should run when user clicks on a button:

here's the test project in [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/github/noonhe/angular-contacts?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

```
  openContacts(){
    this.supported = ('contacts' in (navigator as any) && 'ContactsManager' in window);
    var api = (navigator.contacts || navigator.mozContacts);
    if (api && !!api.select) { // new Chrome API
      api.select(['name', 'email'], {multiple: true})
     .then(function (contacts) {
       console.log('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
       if (contacts.length) {
         console.log('First contact: ' + contacts[0].name + ' (' + contacts[0].email + ')');
       }
      })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Fetching contacts failed: ' + err.name);
    });
  
   } else if (api && !!api.find) { // old Firefox OS API
     var criteria = {
     sortBy: 'familyName',
     sortOrder: 'ascending'
    };
    api.find(criteria)
   .then(function (contacts) {
    console.log('Found ' + contacts.length + ' contacts.');
    if (contacts.length) {
      console.log('First contact: ' + contacts[0].givenName[0] + ' ' + 
     contacts[0].familyName[0]);
    }
  })
  .catch(function (err) {
    console.log('Fetching contacts failed: ' + err.name);
  });
  
} else {
console.log('Contacts API not supported.');
}}
```

but it doesn't work and there's two error :
[image: Navigator Contact Error]

when I test the original example in my phone it works fine, but when I test my own project in my phone it doesn't work.
is there any way to solve this issue?

thanks is advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with the following replacement code (treating `navigator` as `any` type, instead of `Navigator`):

```
var api = ( 
   (navigator as any).contacts || (navigator as any).mozContacts
);
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I tried this before I asked my question here. the error goes away but it still doesn't work. also the supported is always false.

Comment: Trying myself, I found on one of the demo pages the following message: "Sorry! This browser doesn't support the Contact Picker API, which required for this demo. Try enabling the #enable-experimental-web-platform-features in chrome://flags and try again". apparently an experimental API. You may try to enable this flag they mention and see if it works?

Comment: I'm testing it in the chrome browser at my phone. the original example works fine. but the one I have on my own project doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this problem by getting some help.
the declaration should be like this:

```
interface NavigatorContacts extends Navigator {
  readonly contacts: ContactsManager;
}

interface ContactsManager {
  getProperties(): Promise<string[]>;
  select(properties: string[], options?: any): Promise<any>;
}
declare const navigator: NavigatorContacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

The above didn't work for me, but creating a `global.d.ts` file with this content did the trick:

```
declare interface Navigator extends NavigatorExtended {}

interface NavigatorExtended {
    readonly contacts: ContactsManager;
}
// I use only name and tel, but feel free to adjust it https://w3c.github.io/contact-picker/#contacts-manager
type IContact = {
    name: string[],
    tel: string[],
}
interface ContactsManager {
    getProperties(): Promise<string[]>;
    select(properties: string[], options?: any): Promise<IContact[]>;
}
```